# How to Map Multiple class (Association) to a Single Table in Entity Framework 7

Tags: entity-framework

I want to store below entities into one single table. I am getting response from REST apis which is hierarchical JSON but i need to take that JSON structure and Store as flat structure into sql server database. I am using new .net framework and EF 7.

```
CampaignID  (id)
CampaignTitle   (settings.title)
CampaignType    (type)
Status  (status)
EmailsSent  (emails_sent)
SendTime    (send_time)
RecipientsListId    (recipients.list_id)
RptSmryOpens    report_summary.opens
RptSmryUniqOpens    report_summary.unique_opens
RptSmryOpenRate report_summary.open_rate
RptSmryClicks   report_summary.clicks
RptSmrySubsClicks   report_summary.subscriber_clicks
RptSmryClickRate    report_summary.click_rate


public class Campaign
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(@"settings")]
    public Settings Settings { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("report_summary")]
    public ReportSummary ReportSummary { get; set; }
}

public class Settings
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ReportSummary
{

    [JsonProperty("opens")]
    public int Opens { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("unique_opens")]
    public int UniqueOpens { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("open_rate")]
    public double OpenRate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("clicks")]
    public int Clicks { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subscriber_clicks")]
    public int SubscriberClicks { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("click_rate")]
    public double ClickRate { get; set; }
}
```